# Приставка стала корнем?

Tags: этимология

Существует несколько явно родственных русско-европейских слов, одно из которых состоит из приставки. По типу **ПРИСТАВКА**+**КОРЕНЬ***.

То есть, в "западноевропейском языке" мы нередко находим точно такое же слово, с той же семантикой, что и русское, но при этом оно не делится на **ПРИСТАВКУ**+**КОРЕНЬ**, а считается односоставным словом. Приведем примеры:

Русское **3AMÉCTO**, ВМЕСТО, ВЗАМЕН имеет в финском своего родственника A**SAMESTA** — "взамен".
Так же, скажем, и в немецком слово **ZUKLAPPEN** ("захлопнуться") имеет русского родственника **ЗАХЛОПНУТЬ**, имеющее приставку **ЗА**-.

Подобных русско-европейских пар много. Возникает вопрос. Если было заимствование, то по какому закону **приставка** из одного языка могла превратиться в **корень** другого?

И вообще, в подобных этому случаях - кто у кого заимствовал?

Могли ли, скажем, русские позаимствовать у финнов слово **ASAMESTA**, а потом из **ASA-** сделать себе приставку **ЗА-** и вписать это финское слово в русский словарь в значении **ВЗАМЕН**?

Answer (score 1):

Интересно вообще с финским.  Куча слов, которые не могли попасть в язык даже с учетом исторического общепринятого присутствия русских, до ореховского договора,  сотня лет(Невская битва), и после завоевания в 1809 году, еще сотня.
к примеру-путь - matkа, для тех, кто не знает, компас, направление.
люблю тебя ----rakastan sinua  Напрягите мозги сами.
Раком   ----  syöpä, syövän. 
кудахтать в переводе на финский * kotkottaa   куд ку да
приманочная птица в переводе на финский * bulvaani  болван
компания в переводе на финский * porukka   порука.
железо в переводе на финский * rauta  руда
железо в переводе на финский * kovo,  второе от слова ковать, это понятно, но очень редко используется.
переводчик в переводе на финский * kääntäjä   кантовать-переворачивать
переводчик в переводе на финский * tulkki     толковать, толки
народ в переводе на финский * väki
люди, народ
Варианты перевода 
•   kansa  !!!!!!!!
väen (gen.)
А дальше  воин,   Ваенга----военная дорога.
шагай в переводе на финский * kävele  ковыляй.
путь туда и обратно в переводе на финский * edestakainen matka --еду(едешь) за стаканом, как "за спичками", не переводится по собственным корням.
есть ложкой в переводе на финский * lusikoida   ложкой едай!!!

ехать с большой скоростью в переводе на финский * ajaa hurjaa kyytiä     ай –я   ура кати

причем, по отдельности hurjaa – яростный, бешенный, разъяренный,
 kyytiä-ездить, кататься, 
 ajaa-управлять, ездить, вести.
То есть дублирование финского ездить и русского кати, тоже ездить. Тавтология.
топтать в переводе на финский * polkea   ---полька  -танец

одинокий, неженатый в переводе на финский * Sinkku  ----сынку.

отец в переводе на финский * taatto  -  тятя

отдельно речь про книгу-kirja, и все что связано с письменностью.  Карелия-Kirjala исходно.
С очень интересной историей.
kapakka 'кабак', tavara 'товар', piirakka 'пирог', määrä 'количество, мера', majakka 'маяк'. Слово viesti раньше означало 'весть'
и еще множество слов, которые никак не объяснить простым общением с иностранцами и малочисленными иммигрантами.

Comment: Согласимся с Вами.

Действительно, множество слов, никак не объяснить простым общением с иностранцами и малочисленными иммигрантами.

С другой стороны, считать, что эти слова были заимствованы напрямую от праязыка - тоже не правильно. Слишком много времени прошло.

Из-за этого в сравнительном языкознании возникает "странная" проблема. Выходит, что лингвисты по какой-то причине не увидели эти родственные пары, почему-то проигнорировали.

Comment: Академик Зализняк, опережая возможный вопрос из зала, на своей лекции сам же попытался на него ответить. Смысл ответа был такой:
Подобные пары (STRANO - СТРАННЫЙ)встречаются, но очень редко. Между ними нет ничего общего, они не родственники, не когнаты и не заимствования.

Но, помилуйте, как можно доверять уверениям академика о случайности и редкости таких пар, если мы даже невооруженным взглядом видим их целые сотни?

Так что попытка Зализняка отмежеваться от таких русско-европейских "совпадений" ничтожно слаба. 

Или же, он попросту не знает о них. Не интересовался.

Comment: Вы только не смешивайте "тятю", "товар" и "маяк" с "порукой", например. В первом случае вы ломитесь в открытую дверь, во втором – пардон, говорите чушь.

>> Выходит, что лингвисты по какой-то причине не увидели эти родственные пары

Выходит, что лингвисты тупые. Но вы-то не дремлете!

Comment: К сожалению, адекватного ответа на вопрос "Как из русских приставок могли образовываться иностранные слова?" я так и не получил.

Утверждать же, что это, мол, не иностранцы, а мы когда-то заимствовали у них слова, а потом делали из них себе приставки (по типу ZUKLAPPEN=ЗАХЛОПНУТЬ или ASAMESTA=3AMÉCTO), извините, - форменная глупость. 

Не поругиваться надо, а отвечать на вопрос. В этом Вы могли бы проявить свою компетентность.

Но ни Вы, ни настоящие этимологи ответа на этот "щекотливый" вопрос не дадут.

Отсюда и та заготовка Зализняка отвечать - это, мол, случайное редкое совпадение.